# Zurb Foundation 5 Dropdowns (Navbar and Data Content) Occasionally (and at Random) Don't Respond to Click

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I recently started using Foundation 5 (my first experience with Foundation), and I am having an issue where it seems like any element that responds to a `.click` event (e.g. the dropdown menus on the top navbar, the data-dropdowns that show up when an element is clicked) will randomly not work. Clicking will do nothing. This issue is usually resolved by simply reloading the page, however, it happens often enough that it would thoroughly confuse a user, especially a (very valuable) first time user.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this would randomly happen when, most of the time, it works perfectly?

I am using this with Rails 4 and Ruby 2, using the 'foundation-rails' gem.

I've included some examples of my usage in the code below.

Thanks!

**Using data-dropdown-content:**

```
<ul id= <%= "chord-drop-#{chord.id}" %> class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
  <li class="chord-drop-show"><%= link_to 'Show this page', chord %></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Using data-topbar:**

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="is_hover: false">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><%= link_to 'Home Page?', root_path %></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar">Menu</li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <% if current_user %>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <%= link_to 'Keys', '#' %>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><%= link_to 'All Keys', keys_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Add a Key', new_key_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
etc....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by turning off TurboLinks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this right before the `</body>` tag?

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```